# Question on Proof by Induction for formula of Bernoulli numbers

Tags: summation, proof-writing, induction, bernoulli-numbers

I am trying to prove by induction that $F_{n-1}$ = $\frac{-1}{n}\sum_{a=0}^{n-2}{n \choose a} F_a$. The sequence $F_n$ is the Bernoulli numbers, with $F_0=1, F_2=-1/2$ etc. so the formula in question is a recurrence formula for the Bernoulli numbers. I understand how to take the base case, but am struggling with making the inductive step. Should it be something like this:
Base Case: $F_{n-1}$ = $\frac{-1}{n}\sum_{a=0}^{n-3}{n \choose a} F_a$
Inductive Step: $F_{n} = \frac{-1}{n+1}(\sum_{a=0}^{n-1}{n\choose a}F_a + {n\choose n-1}F_{n-1})$. 
I'm then confused about where to go because of the $\frac{-1}{n+1}$
 out in front. Do I try to modify it by algebra to look like $F_{n} = \frac{-1}{n+1}(\sum_{a=0}^{n-1}{{n+1}\choose a}F_a$ ? Please help!

Comment: Surely the index on $F$ under the summation is $a$ and not $n$.

Comment: You are correct, sorry!

Comment: And what is $F_n$?

Comment: $F_n$ is an element of a sequence going to infinity.

Comment: Is that all that you know of $F_n$?

Comment: No, $F_n$ = n!f_n for a second sequence f_n. B1= -1/2, B2= 1/6, B3=0, B4=1/30, B0=1.

Comment: Oh.  So, $F_n=n! B_n$, where $B_n$ are the Bernoulli numbers?

Comment: Yes! I actually hadn't realised they were the Bernoulli numbers, but they are.

Comment: [See this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Recursive_definition)

Comment: The Question's current state is incomplete.  You want to "prove" something, but in the present formulation you merely have a recursive definition of $F_n$, omitting the initial value $F_0$.  Apparently what you really intend to prove is a relationship to the sequence of Bernoulli numbers (although you seem not to have known them by that name).  In any case you should supply a definition of the sequence $B_n$ in the body of the Question (so that then you can say what precisely is to be proved).